# Is it possible to access a public Notion page without OAuth using a supported Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

Is it possible to access public pages without OAuth using an *officially supported* API, like `https://api.notion.com/v1/...`? So far it seems the answer is no (I get 404 if the page is public but hasn't been explicitly shared with my integration), but perhaps I've missed something.

There are tools that work with public pages without login by using the "unofficial" API - `https://notion.so/api/v3/...`, like [Notion Page to HTML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/notion-page-to-html), but I assume that is all reverse engineered internal endpoints that are unsupported and could change without notice.

For a product example (I don't know what they use under the hood, but it's been around longer than official API), [Wunderpresentation](https://wunderpresentation.com/create/notion) lets you paste a URL for a public page and get it formatted as a presentation. I'd like that kind of experience but I'd also prefer to use a supported API if it exists.

Comment: Was also wondering about this. Tried passing invalid credentials, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the public notion page without any auth!

Make POST request to this route "https://www.notion.so/api/v3/loadPageChunk"

with body params like this:

And you'll get the page content successfully!

```
{
 "pageId": "your-page-id",
 "limit": 50,
 "cursor": {
 "stack": []
  },
"chunkNumber": 0,
"verticalColumns": false
}
```

**Note**: just make sure to parse the pageId first using notion-util package or you'll get api error